# How can I pass JSON of flask to Javascript

Tags: javascript, python, flask

I have an index page, which contains a form, fill in the form and sends the data to a URL, which captures the input, and does the search in the database, returning a JSON.
How do I get this JSON, and put it on another HTML page using Javascript?

Form of index:

```
<form action="{{ url_for('returnOne') }}", method="GET">
<p>Nome: <input type="text" name="nome" /></p>
<input type="submit" value="Pesquisar">
</form>
```

My function that returns JSON:

```
@app.route('/userQuery', methods=['GET'])
def returnOne():
    dao = Dao()
    nome = request.args.get('nome')
    return jsonify(json.loads(dao.select(nome)))
```

Comment: You can use jQuery's `$.get('http://localhost:8080/userQuery');` to store the JSON to a local variable.

Comment: and how can i do this? and to call another page html? where I call the page in return?

Comment: I need to get the json and call another page html, i can do this with one route?

Answer (score 6):

Your HTML page after you submit the form. let's call it `response.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>hello</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p id="test"></p>
    <p id="test1"></p>


    <script>
        var b = JSON.parse('{{ a | tojson | safe}}');
        document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = b.test;
        document.getElementById('test1').innerHTML = b.test1;
        console.log(b);
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Your flask function that sends `JOSN` and redirects to `response.html`

```
@app.route('/userQuery', methods=["POST", "GET"])
def returnOne():
        a = {
        "test": "abcd",
        "test1": "efg"
        }
        return render_template("response.html", a=a)
```

Comment: @MatheusAlcântara  Great!! can you please kindly accept the answer if it works for you?

Answer (score -1):

Use ajax request. [This plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#getting-started) transform the submit button in your HTML form to an Ajax submit

```
<script> 
    $(document).ready(function() { 
        // bind 'myForm' and provide a simple callback function 
        $('#myForm').ajaxForm(function(response) { 
            var result = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
            $('#someDiv').innerHTML = result.res
        }); 
    }); 
</script>
```

Use the correct form Id

Comment: in the page that I will return, how can i get this json and pass to html?

Comment: @MatheusAlcântara Assuming you have understood my example above, if you have the following: `var user = JSON.parse('{{ user | tojson | safe}}');` you can simply do `document.getElementById('elementId').innerHTML = user.firstname` to set the first name. Unless I'm missing something.

Comment: sorry, but I don't understand this code, when I get the return of function? I was trying with this code:  <script>
        $.getJSON("{{ url_for('returnOne') }}", function(json) {
            
            var data = `Atualizado em: ${json.atualizado_em}<br>
                        Criado em: ${json.id}<br>
                        Idade: ${json.idade}<br>
                        Nome: ${json.nome}<br>
                        Senha: ${json.senha}`
                        
            
            $(".data").html(data);
        });
        </script>