# python flask and html javascript to return response from mysql and display

Tags: python, html, ajax, flask

I am trying to fetch response JSON from mysql DB using python flask and display it in an html page.

```
@app.route("/augment_withdate1", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def augment_withdate1():
   query = session.get('query', None)
   date = session.get('date', None)
   db = pymysql.connect(host="localhost",  # your host
                     user="root",       # username
                     passwd="",     # password
                     db="pythontesting")   # name of the database

   # Create a Cursor object to execute queries.
   cur = db.cursor()

   # Select data from table using SQL query.
   cur.execute("""SELECT augment,intent FROM response WHERE query= %s 
                AND DATE(date)= %s """, query, date)

   rows = cur.fetchall()
   row_headers=[x[0] for x in cur.description] #this will extract row 
   #headers

   json_data=[]
   for result in rows:
       json_data.append(dict(zip(row_headers,result)))
   return json.dumps(json_data)
```

My html code is :

```
<html>
<script>
      function doWork(){
        $.ajax({
          type: 'post',
          url: "{{ url_for('augment_withdate1') }}",
          contentType: 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
          success: function(result){
            alert(result);  
          },
          error: function(result){
            console.log(result);  
          }
        });
      }
</script>
<tr>
<td align='center'><button onclick="doWork()">Augment</button></form></td>
</tr>
</html>
```

I would like to know : 
1. How can I print the response instead of showing as an alert ?
2. Is there a way fetch all at once from DB and display each column as a button only when user clicks ?

Thanks

Comment: Both answer to your question is "Yes", since the `result` inside your javascript is a json object, now you can do whatever you want. About the second question, the same thing, fetch all the data from your db, send it to Ajax, then you have the json.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49590870/how-can-i-pass-json-of-flask-to-javascript/49591420#49591420 this might give you some idea about how to print your json